# How to calculate average of fields on some if conditions in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I am working on Django where I have two models **Gigs** and **Orders** and I am calculating average Completion time of order of every gig.

in **order** model I have two fields **order start time** (which I'm sending whenever seller accepts the order) and **order completed time**  (which I'm sending when seller delivered) the order.

but I want to calculate average of only those **orders** where `isCompleted = True`

**Models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='buyer_id')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='seller_id')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Gigs,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='gig')
    payment_method= models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=13,default=None)
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(default=1)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=13,default='new order')
    orderStartTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    orderCompletedTime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Gigs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(blank=True, null = True, upload_to= upload_path)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    details = models.TextField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def average_completionTime(self):
        if getattr(self, '_average_completionTime', None):
            return self._average_completionTime
        return self.gig.aggregate(Avg(F('orderCompletedTime') - F('orderStartTime')))
```

**Views.py**

```
class RetrieveGigsAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                ExpressionWrapper(F('gig__orderCompletedTime') - F('gig__orderStartTime'), output_field=DurationField())
            )
        )
    serializer_class = GigsSerializerWithAvgTime
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request , *args, **kwargs):
        return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class GigsSerializerWithAvgTime(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    average_completionTime = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_average_completionTime(self, obj):
        return obj.average_completionTime
    class Meta:
        model = Gigs
        fields = ['id','title','category','price','details','seller','images','average_completionTime']
```

please tell me how can I get the average of only those orders completion time where iscompleted is True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a filter to `Avg` to just aggregate on completed orders based on `isCompleted` like this:

```py
class RetrieveGigsAPI(GenericAPIView, RetrieveModelMixin):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Gigs.objects.annotate(
            _average_completionTime=Avg(
                ExpressionWrapper(F('gig__orderCompletedTime') - F('gig__orderStartTime'), output_field=DurationField()),
                filter=Q(gig__isCompleted=True),
                # ^^^ Add this 
            )
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if isCompleted:
        foo = Gigs.objects.annotate(_average_completionTime=Avg(
                ExpressionWrapper(F('gig__orderCompletedTime') F('gig__orderStartTime'), output_field=DurationField())
            )
        )

        return foo
```